# Jquery move and display content in another field

Tags: jquery, tabs, append

here is what I am trying to do. I want my script to take content (which it does) place it below another div (does this as well). The paragraphs are all hidden until you click one of the list items which will then reveal its paragraph in the div called info. Here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var desc = $('.m-desc');
    var info = $(".desc li");
    var type = $('.type p');
    var part = $('.parts p');
    var paper = $('.paper p');
    var size = $('.size p');
    var imp = $('.imp-area p');
    $(".formFilling-preview").append(desc);
    $(type).hide();
    $('.parts').click(function() {
        $(".info").append(type);
        $(this).children().hide('slow');
    });
    $('.imp-area').click(function() {
        $(".info").append(imp);
    });
    $('.paper').click(function() {
        $(".info").append(paper);
    });
    $('.size').click(function() {
        $(".info").append(size);
    });
    $('.type').click(function() {
        $(".info").append(type);
        $(type).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="m-desc">
    <ul class="desc">
        <li class="type selected">Type:</li>
        <li class="parts">Parts: <p></p></li>
        <li class="paper">Paper Type: <p></p></li>
        <li class="size">Size: <p></p></li>
        <li class="imp-area">Imprint Area: <p></p></li> 
    </ul>
    <div class="info">
        <p style="display: none;">Lorem lipsum epsum</p></div>
    </div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle I setup http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/4mzgV/

Comment: Very confusing trying to work out what you actually want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var desc = $('.m-desc');
    var descLi = $('.m-desc .desc li');
    var info = $('.info');

    $(".formFillingPreview").append(desc);
    descLi.click(function() {
        info.html($('p', $(this)).html());
        $('p', info).show();
    });
});
```

Check it out the whole example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4mzgV/28/

Comment: my appologies for not replying yesterday but ya this is, just I would like the content to replace the old content with new content rather than adding to it.

Comment: I have edited it now, so the script copies the p tag in the selected li element and then replaces all the content in info with it. Remember to vote up and mark it as correct answer if all is good :)